# Android Switch widget force close

Tags: android

Trying to create a switch in android with default ON state and with OnCheckedChangeListener. But application is force closing. What is wrong? please help. New in android development.

```
package com.tiumca2013.smarthousecontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private Switch switch1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Switch1);

    switch1.setChecked(true); // force close

    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()        // force close again
    {   
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"switch 1 ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"switch 1 OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    });


   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    } 


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Using Genymotion AVD instead of default AVD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What version of android do you have?

Comment: 4.1.2  @CommonsWare - my DDMS logcat showing hundreds of errors.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is NullPointException. when I handled this  using try-catch block, the application is executing without any error but again switch1.setChecked(true); is not working.

Comment: Why this NullPointerException is generating? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Any help? I'm stuck here.